# Add column values to reader asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, reader

i want to store all of my ID values from sql database to a reader.

so far i got :

```
string strConnString = "Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True";
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        con.Open();
        str = "select * from CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '"+Session["New"].ToString()+"'";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListofId.Add(reader["Id"].ToString());
        }
```

Got an error in ListofId, what am i missing or need to declare perhaps?
thank you

[image]

Comment: Many people cannot view linked images because of their firewall policies.  Can you post the error details in text?  Displaying the error message as quote works well too (highlight the text and click the Blockquote button).

Comment: got an error here `ListofId.Add(reader["Id"].ToString());` i think i need to declare ListofId somewhere? @ClintB

Comment: You already stated where you got the error.  But what is the error?

Comment: ListofID does not exist.

Comment: Yes, you need to declare ListofId.  You should work through some tutorials on programming with lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if list of id is string then u can use `List<string>` if int `List<int>`

```
List<string> Listofids =  new List<string>(); 
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Listofids .Add(reader["Id"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comments,it seems  you just missed to create an instance for the List object.

Simple,just declare the code as below and it will solve your problem

```
List<string> ListofId= new List<string>();
```

Please let me know if it was  solved your problem

Thanks